# Selecting data based on a specific XML tag of an XML which is stored in one of the column (of data type text) of a table in Sybase database

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, sybase, select-query

The table in Sybase database has a column which is of type 'text' say 'myXML'.
This column stores entire XML. I need to retrieve data based on specific value stored in the XML.
For exmaple, in the below table I need to get all the rows which has the OPTIONAL_TAG in myXML column data.

```
myId | myXML
-------------------------------
1    | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <MAIN_TAG>
         value_01
       <MAIN_TAG>
-----------------------------------------------
2    | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <MAIN_TAG>
         value_01
       <MAIN_TAG>
       <OPTIONAL_TAG></OPTIONAL_TAG>
```

Parsing in java code is one option and another is the like query. But I want to know if there is any other way to do the same in DB itself?
Thanks.